# Benchmark report seems to be slightly broken in 11.3.0

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, version-11.3, benchmarking

I am trying to use 11.3 to Benchmark.

Something is strange in the opened report.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the Message said,

[image]

What's up?

Comment: The same behavior on my `Windows 8.1`.

Comment: Can confirm the break on Windows 10.

Comment: I can also confirm, although that the detailed timings are little bit more readable. Another notable annoyance is that the documentation are sometimes broken, sometimes the red rectangle shown just like the beginning of the picture in your post, but after reopen it, it disappears.

Comment: Can confirm the break on Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

This issue should now be fixed automatically for users within 3 days. If you want to get the fix immediately, run

```
PacletInstall["Benchmarking"]
```